# Can SQL server instead of update force insert a new row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

Is it possible in SQL Server 2008+ to force an `UPDATE` statement on table to be transformed into `INSERT` statement, thus creating new row with the old and updated columns?

Comment: I think this is done with the `MERGE` statement.

Comment: @MikeChristensen Yes I can see how I could do that, but I wanted to achieve this by not changing existing queries in my application, by just adjusting the way query is received for a particular table.

Comment: `Instead of update` trigger ?

Comment: I think the OP is referring to an SCD mechanism,

Comment: @TMNT2014 Yes, I need to create version control of the current process, and I need a simple and fast solution.

Comment: @a1ex07 How would I use Instead of update trigger to create new record with updated values? Does it pass any arguments down the stream that I could use for an insert statement?

Comment: @ skmasq: inside the trigger body you have access to `inserted` and `deleted` pseudo-tables that contains new and old values respectively.

Comment: Here's a link with some sample code - http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/01/24/sql-server-how-to-use-instead-of-trigger-guest-post-by-vikas-munjal-koenig-solutions/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is a typical scenario for an `INSTEAD OF UPDATE TRIGGER`.

Create the following trigger on your table and it will insert a row for each update made on your table. you can have a bit more logic inside your trigger but this is just a basic definition just to give you some idea.

Inside your INSTEAD of UPDATE trigger you will have access to two system tables `Inserted` and `deleted`.

`Inserted` table will hold new values for the row that was being updated by the Update statement.

`Deleted` table will hold Old values for the row that was being updated by the Update statement.

### Demo Trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_Table_Instead_Of_Update
ON TABLE_NAME
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

 INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME(Col1, Col2 , Col3)
 SELECT Col1, Col2 , Col3
 FROM inserted 

END
```

Comment: I see how this would work for `UPDATE Col1,Col2,Col3` statement, but would it set `Col3` to a default not the old value in `UPDATE Col1,Col2` statement?

Comment: If a column is not being updated in an update statement, it will be present in both `inserted` and `deleted` tables but its value will be the same.